# cannot see postman test results azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, postman

I have some postman collections and I would like to run them in azure devops,
for whatever the reason my tests are not published.

What Am I missing?
If I remove  "reporters: junit i can see the result in the step. I was expecting a tab "test" next to summary

```
resources:
- repo: self
  clean: true
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: npm

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: false    
    customCommand: 'install newman -g'
 
- task: NewmanPostman@4
  displayName: 'Postman tests'
  inputs:
    collectionFileSource: 'my.postman_collection.json'
    environmentSourceType: none
    reporters: junit
    ignoreRedirect: false
    bail: false    
    sslInsecure: false
    htmlExtraDarkTheme: false
    htmlExtraLogs: false
    htmlExtraTestPaging: false

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit' # Options: JUnit, NUnit, VSTest, xUnit
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.xml'
```

Comment: debug it one by one than as whole first just keep a static postman junit report and see if you are able to publish it , then delete and run postman and see junit is getting published . then add step to remove previous report each time for new run and validate junit is created each run, then integrate the two solutions together and see whats going wrong

Comment: Hi for starters I just created a collection  with a single test to see if worked and I can see working in the step in the pipeline. I am totally new to junit report where can I get one? Why is the pipeline  not publishing the report

Comment: junit report is generated in the newman folder in the working directory of your newman , you have to publish that using publishtest result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What Am I missing? If I remove "reporters: junit i can see the result in the step. I was expecting a tab "test" next to summary

Based on my test, I could reproduce your issue.

Here are the following points, you need to check:

1. The XML file path in Publish Test Result task.

By default, the Junit xml file will be saved at newman folder.
[image]

You could set the file path with the following path:

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results **/*/*.xml'
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/*/*.xml'
```

You can also change the Junit file output path: **reporterJUnitExport field** in NewmanPostman task

**Example:**

```
- task: NewmanPostman@4
  displayName: 'Newman - Postman'
  inputs:
    collectionFileSource: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    Contents: 'kevintest123.postman_collection.json'
    environmentSourceType: none
    ignoreRedirect: false
    bail: false
    sslInsecure: false
    reporters: junit
    htmlExtraDarkTheme: false
    htmlExtraLogs: false
    htmlExtraTestPaging: false
    reporterJUnitExport: '$(Build.sourcesdirectory)\Results\junitReport.xml'
```

2. You need to make sure that the Json file contain the test. When you Export the files in Postman, you need to add the content in test tab:

[image]

Here is a doc about [Add test in Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/).

Then you could publish the test result to the test tab successfully via Publish test Restlt task.

[image]

Or you will get the following issue and the test result Junit xml file doesn't contain the test result:

[image]

**Update:**

> Cannot find "continue on error" anywhere.anyideas

Yaml Editor

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results **/*/*.xml'
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/*/*.xml'
  continueOnError: true
```

Classic  editor

[image]

Comment: mmm I tried just that in my tests but still no luck , let me follow your steps and see if I do something different

Comment: Hi it works however noticed that if you have a test that fails the test summary does not show as it does not get to the publishresult task. Cannot find "continue on error" anywhere.anyideas .

Comment: Hi @developer9969. You could add condition to Publish test result task. Please refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

Junit report is generated in the newman folder in the current directory. You change this location as:

```
--reporter-junit-export a.xml 
--reporter-junit-export folder/a.xml
```

this will generate report as a.xml or a.xml in the folder/directory you specified.

you have to publish that using publishtest result , if you are not using --reporter-junit-export  , then make sure workingdirectory for all the steps are same.

else give full path as :

```
--reporter-junit-export c:/folder/a.xml
```

and

in step give the full path of report:

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit' # Options: JUnit, NUnit, VSTest, xUnit
    testResultsFiles: 'c:/folder/a.xml'
```